# the Classification of threads in browser

Tags: javascript, user-interface, browser

Is there an official classification of threads in browser? I want to write an article related with browser thread concepts. Is the following classification correct?
Javascript interpreter thread, GUI rendering thread, event handler thread, timing thread, http request thread...

If you have more official detail about it, please tell me with a list or give me the related links, thank you.

Comment: Which classification of threads does setTimeout belong to ?

Comment: There are no official threads in the browser, so there's no official classification either. Notice that there are even single-threaded browser implementations!

Answer (score 0):

[Behind the scenes of modern web browsers](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm)

[The JavaScript Event Loop: Explained](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have  read the link, but It is not specific, could you tell me which classification does setTimeout belong to?